# Valgrind, Blocks Are Definitely Lost even though I free?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind, free

> Small Note, Please Ignore the use of malloc instead of new and the use
> of my own containers instead of vector etc... The point of this code
> was to practice the basics.

When I ran Valgrind I get:

```
==24855== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24855==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 2 blocks
==24855==   total heap usage: 12,999 allocs, 12,997 frees, 675,432 bytes allocated
==24855==
==24855== 0 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==24855==    at 0x4C29F73: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==24855==    by 0x4014ED: ImageTagger::GetAllSegmentsByLabel(int, int**, int**, int*) (ImageTagger.cpp:100)
==24855==    by 0x402EB6: GetAllSegmentsByLabel (library2.cpp:59)
==24855==    by 0x403A8B: OnGetAllSegmentssByLabel (main2.cpp:345)
==24855==    by 0x4033A6: parser (main2.cpp:172)
==24855==    by 0x403135: main (main2.cpp:95)
==24855==
```

But the allocated block is freed in main, what's the problem? Here is the relevant part of my code:

`ImageTagger.cpp`:

```
StatusType ImageTagger::GetAllSegmentsByLabel(int label, int **images, int **segments, int *numOfSegments) {
    if (label <= 0 || images == nullptr || segments == nullptr || numOfSegments == nullptr) {
        return INVALID_INPUT;
    }
    *numOfSegments = Match_Num(image_tree->root, label);
    int *imageArr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (*numOfSegments));
    if (imageArr == nullptr) {
        return ALLOCATION_ERROR;
    }
    int *segArr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (*numOfSegments));
    if (segArr == nullptr) {
        free(imageArr);
        return ALLOCATION_ERROR;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    InorderTraversal(image_tree->root, imageArr, segArr, &counter, (*numOfSegments), label);
    *images = imageArr;
    *segments = segArr;
    if ((*numOfSegments) == 0) {
        *images = *segments = nullptr;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

And in `main2.cpp` I have (Notice both free lines at the end, how is that lost?):

```
static errorType OnGetAllSegmentssByLabel(void* DS, const char* const command) {
    int courseID, numOfLabels;
    int *images, *segments;
    ValidateRead(sscanf(command, "%d", &courseID), 1, "%s failed.\n", commandStr[GETALLSEGMENTSSBYLABEL_CMD]);
    StatusType res = GetAllSegmentsByLabel(DS, courseID, &images, &segments, &numOfLabels);

    free(images);
    free(segments);

    return error_free;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if `(*numOfSegments) == 0` is true in `GetAllSegmentsByLabel`?

In that case you have still allocated 2 blocks of 0 bytes and they are lost because you set both pointers to `nullptr` before exiting the function in the if statement.

Every malloc including `malloc(0)` must be freed.

Comment: Also sanitizers are quite a good alternative to Valgrind - `-fsanitize=leak,address` and `-fsanitize=memory` (clang-only).